# One Inter mediator Service can work for all integrations

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

Below is my rest endpoint which will be triggered by 3rd party game providers for following requests

1) /authenticate : This service will triggered by 3rd party game provider to validate the token given by my server. On success my server will return the response in a format which was requested by 3rd party. Response my contain userId, sessionId, token, balance, etc.. and it may hash value in header. (Similarly I've few more services)

I am not able to implement a generic solution to authenticate the user, because each 3rd party game provider have different request and response formates and different request and response parameters.

How I can make a mediator to solve this, so that I can do smooth integration even if the providers have different structure.

I'm using Spring Boot REST service.

Comment: You should look into Single Sign On (SSO) solutions. SSO will allow you to integrate with external identity providers using standard protocols like OAuth and SAML.

Comment: SSO is not right solution for my requirement, these services will call back-end there wont be any user interaction. This authentication request send when any player tries to launch a game. The provider will send the token or authentication parameters to my server to validate on success response they will open the game to play